# Which NavigationController Method runs on every view reload (TabBarItem)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I have a NavigationController then a TabBarController which has Four Tabs.
I wanted to display Different titles on TopBar when a Different Tab is selected.
One way was to Embed each TabBarItem View into Navigation Controller but for some reason this doesn't seems the correct way, i wanted to apply this via code.

I managed accomplish this by using this code: (Products_ViewController.m custom class)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UINavigationController *navCon  = (UINavigationController*) [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    navCon.navigationItem.title = @"Products";
}
```

But the problem is now when a tab is clicked First time, it changes the title but then it doesn't. I then applied the same code on `-(void)viewDidAppear{}` but still the same result.

How can i manage to display navigation top bar title (or run the above code) whenever the tab bar item is clicked or the view is shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in the `Products_ViewController.m` class and execute your code in the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.

```
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {  
         UINavigationController *navCon  = (UINavigationController*) [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
         navCon.navigationItem.title = @"Products";
    }
```

In the `viewDidLoad` method you have to set the `delegate` to `self`.

Comment: Thank you, do i add it into the Products_ViewController.m custom class OR do i have to create a custom class for UITabBarItem or UITabBarController ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot this, you have to write the code into the Products_ViewController.m class.

Comment: ok, i added the code but i really don't understand how to implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate in the Products_ViewController.m. Can you please explain a bit more? Thx

Comment: Btw, i added this `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;` into the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method `(Products_ViewController.m)` and added the same thing into the another tab next to it, they are changing the Tob Bar Titles but not changing it back when i click the second time. Let's suppose if i have two tabs `Products` and `About Us`, when i click Products 1st time, it changes the title, then i click `About Us`, it changes too, but then if i again click on `Products`, Title will remain to `About Us`.

Comment: Yeah, the reason for that is, that there can be only one delegate for a `UITabbarController`, so the delegate changes the first times, because `viewDidLoad` gets called, but then the views are load and the method won´t be called again. So you could try setting the delegate in the `viewDidAppear:`or the `viewWillAppear:` function, because they are called even, when the view is loaded.

Comment: still not working, seems like `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` doesn't work at all! Because i simply used `NSLog` only to see if the log messages are coming through whenever i click the tabs, but nope, they are not coming through so probably these methods are not being invoked at all.

Comment: i guess i should go ahead by embedding each tab item view into the navigation controller. sigh :(